# rethinkdb get records by createdDate

Tags: date, rethinkdb

we are using rethinkdb with nodejs. I have a user table and i want to get all user records inserted today and yesterday like below sql query.

```
select * from user where DATEDIFF(day,createdDate ,GETDATE()) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/#date

```
r.table("users").filter(function(user) {
return user("birthdate").date().eq(r.now().date())
})
```